# How to find out IP address of the user who dropped a sql server user Databse

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-administration

I created a SQL Login "TestUser" and granted that user DBO privileges on "TESTDB" database. I logged in as Testuser and dropped TESTDB.

I was able to find out who dropped the database by looking at the schema changes history report.

I would like to know how can I find out the ipaddress or computer name where I ran this command from. (If multiple people are using the same sql login this will help me identify who ran the drop command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try like below

```
SELECT      c.session_id, s.host_name, s.login_name, s.status, st.text, s.login_time, s.program_name, *
FROM        sys.dm_exec_connections c
INNER JOIN  sys.dm_exec_sessions s ON c.session_id = s.session_id
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(most_recent_sql_handle) AS st
ORDER BY    c.session_id
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. Exactly what I am looking for. Thank you.